# Where does this green plane fuselage piece come from?

Tags: part-identification, city

It has the year 2005 on it and the number 22988 I think.  Anyone know what it is?

[image: part pic]

Answer (score 9):

It's the rear end of an aircraft fuselage. It's part number is [54701c02](http://rebrickable.com/parts/54701c02).

[image: 54701]

It's from one of these two sets:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I'm really bad at figuring out these parts.  I guess the number I found on it wasn't the part #.  When I searched for green pieces...nothing like this large fuselage showed up. Thanks again :).